# html a onclick window open not working on ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is the code:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "savePart",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (jsonStr)
    {
        var result = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

        var materialQualification = '<a href="files/material_qualification/'+result.materialQualification+'" onclick="window.open(this.href, "mywin","left=330,top=20,width=800,height=800,toolbar=0,resizable=0"); return false;">'+mqFormat+'</a>';

        var newrow = $('<tr class="trClick" id="'+result.formID+'" data-toggle="modal"><td align="center" class="number">'+materialQualification+'</td></tr>';

        $("#tData tbody").prepend(newrow);
    }
});
```

When above code execute, `window.open` is not working. When I click `<a></a>`, it's not show me new window open.

Is there any way how to set it? Or Am I do something wrong there?

UPDATED:
When `<a></a>` clicked, it show me error in console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be binding click event handlers inline. Instead, you can simply listen to a click event bubbling up from the anchor element, at the level of an element that is already present at runtime, e.g. `$('#tData tbody').on('click', 'a', function() {...})`

Comment: Did you see any errors in inspect window?

Comment: @TAHATEMURII Yes, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: There's quotes errors... use escape quotes

Comment: @HiDayurieDave, try my answer , i just test it and it is working ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line in your code and try. There is a mashup with a `"` and `'`. I use `'` with slace `\'` instead of `"` inside `window.open` function.

```
var materialQualification = '<a href="files/material_qualification/'+result.materialQualification+'" onclick="window.open(this.href, \'mywin\',\'left=330,top=20,width=800,height=800,toolbar=0,resizable=0\'); return false;">'+mqFormat+'</a>';
```

Comment: @HiDayurieDave , don't forgot to accept answer , so it will helpful to others

Answer (score 1):

Onclick not working because of `"` double quote in the below line.

```
var materialQualification = '<a href="files/material_qualification/'+result.materialQualification+'" onclick="window.open(this.href, "mywin","left=330,top=20,width=800,height=800,toolbar=0,resizable=0"); return false;">'+mqFormat+'</a>';
```

Add `\` before `"` double quote and add `'` single quote in place of `"` double quote in `window.open` function., checkout below line

```
var materialQualification = '<a href="files/material_qualification/'+result.materialQualification+'" onclick="window.open(this.href, \'mywin\',\'left=330,top=20,width=800,height=800,toolbar=0,resizable=0\'); return false;">'+mqFormat+'</a>';
```

Comment: Tried, but still new window not open. When click the link sometimes I got error in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: what you are trying to do with this line `var newrow = $('<tr class="trClick" id="'+result.formID+'" data-toggle="modal"><td align="center" class="number">'+materialQualification+'</td></tr>';`